# Will removing `static` from a private function break ABI compatibility?

Tags: c, backwards-compatibility, abi

Say you're working on the source of a library that needs to maintain ABI compatibility. This library has a .c file that defines a `static` function like so:

```
static int
wl_message_count_arrays(const struct wl_message *message)
{
    // ...
}
```

This function is not exposed in any exported headers, but I would like to expose it in a private header. To do so, the function can not be marked `static`. Would removing the `static` modifier of the function signature change the ABI?

Comment: *Changing the ABI* and *changing the ABI so that it breaks existing programs* is two different things. You're definitely doing the first, but maybe not the second.

Comment: Nope. I guess the only risk is name clashes, in case there's another function with the same name, but with a different interface.

Comment: @tofro If you add an answer that explains your comment I will happily select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are several points to consider:

- Does it change the ABI?

  Yes, because now there is a new public symbol. There's no difference between adding a new function and removing `static` from an existing function as far as the ABI is concerned.
- Does it break compatibility?

  It definitely does in the other direction: Programs linked against the new version of the library that make use of the new symbol won't run with older versions of the library.
- OK, but what about users of the old library that want to upgrade?

  In that case there's a possibility that they define a symbol with the same name themselves, leading to conflicts with the new library. Technically this is a breaking change.

  But if the symbol is "namespaced" (e.g. if all the names from the library use a `foo_` prefix and the new symbol does, too), then I'd consider this change morally non-breaking and the new ABI compatible with the old one.